# MySQL query to see which rows do not have a counterpart

Tags: mysql, distinct

I need to select the email of the users who have not yet reviewed a completed booking.
I of course want no more than one email per booking that has not yet been reviewed, and here is the problem. I´ve tried selecting DISTINCT bid (b.bid and r.booking_id are the numbers to look for) and also a GROUP BY solution but got neither of them to work.

They still might be the solution though, I just couldn´t make it work. For example, testing with just two reviews in my DB where the bid and booking_id do not match I get two rows for the same booking:

```
username bid booking_id
mail@mail.mail 9 8
mail@mail.mail 9 45
```

This is the query I last run to solve the problem, but as you can see above the result was the same. Where am I wrong here ? Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT u.username, b.bid, r.booking_id
FROM users u, reviews r, bookings b
WHERE u.id = b.id_booker
AND b.status =  'FINISHED'
AND b.bid NOT IN (SELECT booking_id FROM reviews WHERE 1)
```

EDIT: structure of the three tables - only relevant columnnames

```
Users TABLE 
id           // - auto increment value
email        // The emails to which I will send reminders if no review has been posted

Reviews TABLE
rid          // - auto increment value
booking_id   // ID of the booking to which the review refers (bookings.bid)
id_author    // ID of the user who wrote the review (users.id)

Bookings TABLE
bid          // ID of the booking (reviews.booking_id) - auto increment value
id_booker    // ID of the user who made the booking (users.id)
status       // Only looking for finished bookings in this query
```

Comment: post your db tables structure to see how the tables should joined

Comment: I didn't understand your problem can you give an example and sample output

Comment: The problem with the query as it is now and as it gets whenever I stupidly compose it myself is that I get multiple values for the same problem - as stated in the text above I get the same email twice in the example both referring to the same bid (booking id). This would result in spam

Comment: If you are not using the `b.bid, r.booking_id`  remove them from the query and use `distinct`

Comment: Meherzad could you put that as an answer so I can checked it since it actually worked :P. Easy, good solution, my inexperience in MySQL queries made me not try it earlier, the DISTINCT keyword tricked me there i guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could first select all the ids from Bookings.id_booker.
Then substract the id's from the user who have allready submited a review.

```
SELECT id_booker
FROM Bookings
WHERE id_booker NOT IN ( 
    SELECT id_author
    FROM Reviews
)
```

That would get you the id's from all the users who have not submitted a review.

Last step would be to get the email adressess of these users.

```
SELECT DISTINCT email
FROM Bookings
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.id = Bookings.id_booker
WHERE id_booker NOT IN ( 
    SELECT id_author
    FROM Reviews
)
```

I would prefer to only use sub-queries since you only need data from the Users table.
But MySQL has serious performance issues on sub-queries so this could be a good solution.